# VBA: Won't allow me to change the RecordSource of another Form in Microsoft Access

Tags: database, forms, vba, ms-access-2010

I'm working on a database that holds and displays cources for employees, every employee has a different date on which he or she has to do the specific course again. I made a few tabels that hold all the information. I can display the information in a form, this form contains a few buttons which allow me to choose between different Queries. All Queries output the same type of data in the same form. For easy reference I will call this form **FormA**.

This all works fine but a few hours ago I added a button which should allow me to update the information of a certain record. This updating happens in a different form lets call it **FormB**. In the old situation I used a specific form for every training but I thought that this was every unefficient. I made a form that can display the information of every query. The problem that i'm encountering is the fact that whenever I press the button to update a certain record. It always displays the information of the top record in the query/form. I have been stuck on this for a few hours now and I just cant get it to work. If I manually set the RecordSource of **FormB** to the right query it all works like it should. But this requires me to make a lot of the same forms.

I will try to link all the code that I think is relevant. If something else is needed please say so.

The code used on the update button placed on **FormA**:

```
Private Sub btnUpdate_Click()
Dim stDocName As String


If Forms!FormA.RecordSource = "QryFG" Then

  stDocName = "FormB"

  ' we open first the form:
  DoCmd.OpenForm stDocName, , , "peoplesoftnr = " & Me!PeopleSoftNr

  ' we then set up it's RecordSource:
  Forms!FormB.RecordSource = "QryFG"

End If
```

This if statement is repeated five times of all the different trainings, they are all the same so I won't include them in this post.

The code fills my textboxes in my **FormB**. But it always picks the top record. Even when I press the button that is not in the same row (**FormA**). When I comment out the following line:

```
' Forms!FormB.RecordSource = "QryFG":
```

And manually set the QryFG as the RecordSource of **FormB**, it does what its supposed to do. But by doing this I will have to create alot of the same forms. I hope there is a better way of doing this. Thanks in advance for your time and efford. My native language is not English so please ignore the spelling and grammar mistakes ;).

Thanks again!

Joeri Rommers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By setting the form's recordsource, you overwrite the filter that you previously set in `DoCmd.OpenForm`, so it shows all records of `QryFG`, starting with the first.

There are multiple ways around that, e.g.

```
' Open without filter
DoCmd.OpenForm stDocName
' Limit recordsource to current record
Forms!FormB.RecordSource = "SELECT * FROM QryFG WHERE peoplesoftnr = " & Me!PeopleSoftNr
```

or set the filter after changing the recordsource:

```
DoCmd.OpenForm stDocName
With Forms(stDocName)
    .RecordSource = "QryFG"
    .Filter = "peoplesoftnr = " & Me!PeopleSoftNr
    .FilterOn = True
End With
```

If the form "flickers" while doing that, you can open it with `WindowMode:=acHidden` and then set it to `.Visible = True` after changing RecordSource/Filter.

Comment: Both solutions work great! Thanks a lot, you saved me!